# How to increase the limit of number of open files for elasticsearch in debian?

Tags: memory-management, elasticsearch

Can any one help me out on how to increase the maximum no.of opened files for elasticsearch in Debian?
Also on how to increase its memory limits?
And how to check the whether the memory limits are applied?
I have a file "/etc/init.d/elasticsearch" which has the setting like:

```
`#! /bin/sh`
`### BEGIN INIT INFO`
`# Provides:          elasticsearch`
`# Required-Start:    $all`
`# Required-Stop:     $all`
`# Default-Start:     2 3 4 5`
`# Default-Stop:      0 1 6`
`# Short-Description: Starts elasticsearch`
`# Description:       Starts elasticsearch using start-stop-daemon`
`### END INIT INFO`

`ES_HOME=/usr/local/elasticsearch`
`ES_MIN_MEM=256m`
`ES_MAX_MEM=2g`
`DAEMON=$ES_HOME/bin/elasticsearch`
`NAME=elasticsearch`
`DESC=elasticsearch`
`PID_FILE=/var/run/$NAME.pid`
`LOG_DIR=/var/log/$NAME`
`DATA_DIR=/var/lib/$NAME`
`WORK_DIR=/tmp/$NAME`
`CONFIG_FILE=/etc/$NAME/elasticsearch.yml`
`DAEMON_OPTS="-p $PID_FILE -Des.config=$CONFIG_FILE -Des.path.home=$ES_HOME -Des.path.logs=$LOG_DIR -Des.path.data=$DATA_DIR -Des.path.work=$WORK_DIR"`


`test -x $DAEMON || exit 0
 set -e
 case "$1" in
  start)
    echo -n "Starting $DESC: "
    mkdir -p $LOG_DIR $DATA_DIR $WORK_DIR
    if start-stop-daemon --start --pidfile $PID_FILE --startas $DAEMON -- $DAEMON_OPTS
    then
        echo "started."
    else
        echo "failed."
    fi
    ;;
  stop)
    echo -n "Stopping $DESC: "
    if start-stop-daemon --stop --pidfile $PID_FILE
    then
        echo "stopped."
    else
        echo "failed."
    fi
    ;;
  restart|force-reload)
    ${0} stop
    sleep 0.5
    ${0} start
    ;;
  *)
    N=/etc/init.d/$NAME
    echo "Usage: $N {start|stop|restart|force-reload}" >&2
    exit 1
    ;;
esac

exit 0
```

Any help on these would be greatly appreciated..
Thanks In Advance..

Answer (score 0):

Try to start elasticsearch with -Des.max-open-files=true to print at startup how many files can be opened on your system or do

```
cat /proc/sys/fs/file-max
```

Note the number

```
sudo vi /etc/sysctl.conf
```

Add a line with max files (previous number):

```
fs.file-max = 100000
```

Logout and login again. It should work.

For memory, just edit ES_MIN_MEM and ES_MAX_MEM and put the same value for both (about 60% of your total RAM on this box)

HTH

Comment: I added this `-Des.max-open-files=true` at the end to above code 
`DAEMON_OPTS="-p $PID_FILE -Des.config=$CONFIG_FILE -Des.path.home=$ES_HOME -Des.path.logs=$LOG_DIR -Des.path.data=$DATA_DIR -Des.path.work=$WORK_DIR"`
it's showing the maximum no.of opened files as : "**[bootstrap                ] max_open_files [996]**"
And when I run the command **cat /proc/sys/fs/file-max**, it gave me this number **819013**

Comment: so shall i add the line `fs.file-max = 819013`to **/etc/sysctl.conf**    Also can you please explain what does this mean or how does it affect elasticsearch? Does it increase the max number of opened file from **996** to **819013**?

Comment: Also is it necessary to set the memory size of **ES_MIN_MEM** and **ES_MAX_MEM** to same value? my Debian sys has also other programs installed in it like RabbitMQ Server, My SQL, along with some other ones...and it has total of 8gb memory...so if i set the elasticsearch memory to 60% of total memory, does it affect the other programs? plz explain.